# Correction in DFS Strategy

Tags: algorithm, depth-first-search

I tried doing DFS for the first time and this is the code that I came up with.
Can someone please guide me as to why my DFS code is wrong?

```
void DFS(vector<vector<int>>& adj, vector<bool>& visited, int x) {
    if (!visited[x]) {
        visited[x] = true;
        cout << x << " ";
        for (int i = 0; i < adj[x].size(); i++) {
            DFS(adj, visited, adj[x][i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using recursion? What if adj is too large, your stack will get consumed and it will result in stack overflow! Use `stack<>` data structure instead. And what does `x` signify?

Comment: Please post the whole code, even `int main()` function.

Comment: I think everything is ok here. Most probably there are bugs in other parts of your code. Could you please share the whole code?

Comment: Please post [mre] and add language tag.

Comment: @c0der I think this qualifies as a Minimal Example

Comment: @DollarAkshay it is minimal indeed. I agree. However would you agree that it is not complete and not reproducible ? To qualify as such it should be what I call CPR: copy-paste-run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to reset you `visited` before exiting the node. Otherwise you are visiting every node only once

At the end of the if condition you need to add `visited[x] = false`

Comment: Why would you want to explore a node more than once ?

Comment: @c0der Lets say you have a 4 node fully connected graph where you have now your stack is like `A B C D`. Now since you have marked all of them as visited you will not be able to explore anything from `A C`. Basically DFS is supposed to explore all possible paths in a graph.

Comment: The visited is there to ensure that you do not visit the same node 2 times like `A B A C`.